# How to set environment variables in Dockerfile and start parent image

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile that has a entrypoint.sh file which exports some Postgres variable.
Then I want to start the parent docker container which is referenced in "FROM pactfoundation/pact-broker" image.  Looking at github for it's Dockerfile [github pact broker](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-broker-docker) it has CMD ["config.ru"] at the end.  So I did similar to that in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM pactfoundation/pact-broker
  
COPY entrypoint.sh .

CMD ["config.ru"]
```

When I execute my docker run command:

```
docker run --rm -e POSTGRES_PORT=5433 -e POSTGRES_DBNAME=pactsd -e POSTGRES_URL=localhost -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -e POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres --name pact sonamsamdupkhangsar/pact:test -d
```

I see my entrypoint.sh echo statement and the container is dead.

```
setting pact broker database variables
```

How do I start the parent container after setting my envrionment variables in my entrypoint.sh file?

I also tried with the following:

```
FROM pactfoundation/pact-broker
  
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=${POSTGRES_URL}
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PORT=$POSTGRES_PORT

RUN echo "PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PORT: $PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PORT"
```

Yet, when I run my built docker image I still don't see the variables being set.  I tried both approaches for "${}" and "$" for env var setting.

Comment: Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run; the `-d` option in your `docker run` command replaces the Dockerfile `CMD`.  If you mean it to be a `docker run` option ("detached") it needs to be before the image name.

Answer (score 0):

You've to set your environment variables using the ENV in your docker file.

As each step executed at different containers which altogether builds the image if you set via shell scripts it won't work. Consider using the ENV command to set it

Ref: [DOCKERFILE ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

Comment: I have set the enironment variables but the parent container is not using the set variables.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that those environment variables that you are passing in at run-time with '-e' parameter are not yet defined at **build-time** as the ENV instructions are executed at build-time only.

E.g. at build-time this line you have:

```
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
```

becomes this line:

```
ENV PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=
```

as '${POSTGRES_DBNAME}' evaluates to empty at build-time. Then, when run-time happens, you are defining all your POSTGRES_ environment variables as parameters so they will indeed exist in the container, BUT no further instructions will be executed to set the PACT_BROKER_ environment variables to any other values.

**Proposed solution**: I would recommend the simplest approach if you can make it work to just use the environment variables 'directly' however you define them as parameters. I.e. either change the names of your '-e' parameters to PACT_BROKER_'s or use the POSTGRES_ environment variables in your container. Either way you would remove the ENV lines from the Dockerfile.

If you really-really need to set the environment variables to other names at **run-time**, then you should be able to do this by writing to the appropriate 'startup' file in the Dockerfile (making sure to **literally** write the '$'s to the file so they could be dereferenced at run-time).